# How can I combine them one by one when I have multiple arrays in Javscript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have array objects called heatstatus and triperrors. At this time, I want to get the value of the variable called answer, which is the sum of the objects of heatstatus and triperrors.

But when I run my code, it doesn't merge. What should I do?

this is my code

```
    const heatstatus = [
        {
            equipId: "1"
        },
        {
            equipId: "2"
        },
        {
            equipId: "3"
        },
    ]


    const triperrors = [
        {
            equipId: "11",
        },
        {
            equipId: "22",
        },
        {
            equipId: "33",
        }

    ]

    const answer = Object.assign(heatstatus, triperrors)

    // expected answer 
    const answer = [
        {
            equipId: "1",
            equipId: "11",
        },
        {
            equipId: "2",
            equipId: "22",
        }
        {
            equipId: "3",
            equipId: "33",
        }
    ]
```

Comment: _"What should I do?"_ - Use a loop. And read what `Object.assign()` does and how: _"The Object.assign() method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more **source objects** to a target object. It returns the modified target object."_

Comment: Are you **absolutely certain** (_I suspect you are not_) that you want the result that you have provided in your expected answer?  because you can just type `triperrors` to get it.  (this is because of the way JavaScript behaves with duplicate property names in object literals -- it takes the last value)  You notice you have `equipId` properties specified twice, right?

Comment: Your expected answer or expectation is incorrect. answer is a collection of objects. These objects cant have duplicate keys like you have in the expectation. Something looks off with your understanding, which when improved, should make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `aray.map` method on one of two array to transform each element of this array and add the missing propetry from the another one if it exist

```js
const heatstatus = [{
    equipId: "1"
  },
  {
    equipId: "2"
  },
  {
    equipId: "3"
  },
];


const triperrors = [{
    tripId: "11",
  },
  {
    tripId: "22",
  },
  {
    tripId: "33",
  }

];

const answer = heatstatus.map((status, index) => {
  return {
    ...status,
    tripId: (triperrors[index]) ? (triperrors[index].tripId) : 'default value'
  }
});

console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const heatstatus = [
        {
            equipId: "1"
        },
        {
            equipId: "2"
        },
        {
            equipId: "3"
        },
    ];


    const triperrors = [
        {
            equipId: "11",
        },
        {
            equipId: "22",
        },
        {
            equipId: "33",
        }

    ];
    
    let result = heatstatus.map((status,index)=>{
        let result = {equipId:'',tripId:''};
        result.equipId = status.equipId;
        result.tripId = triperrors[index].equipId;
        return result;
    });
    console.log(result)
```